# React setState reusable

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to create a function that can be used to set state on different key values passed in on the event. When I log the state it still in its initial state with empty strings on each key. I tried with and without [] on the key value in the setState. Thank you

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        Day:'',
        Open:'',
        Close:''
    }
  }

  logState(){
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  pushTime(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Clicked ', event.target.id, event.target.value);
    var id = event.target.id
    console.log(typeof id);
    this.setState({[event.target.id]:event.target.name})
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the `pushTime` function so that it can access the state. For that you can make use of `arrow function` or `bind it in constructor`. Also `setState` takes time to mutate the state so you must call the logState function inside the `setState` callback like the below example

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        Day:'',
        Open:'',
        Close:''
    }
  }

  logState(){
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  pushTime = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Clicked ', event.target.id, event.target.value);
    var id = event.target.id
    this.setState({[id]:event.target.name}, function() {
      this.logState();
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input type='checkbox' id='Day' name='Day' onClick={this.pushTime} value='Day'/>
      <input type='checkbox' id='Open' name='Open' value='Open' onClick={this.pushTime}/>
      <input type='checkbox' id='Close' name='Close' value='Close' onClick={this.pushTime}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Shubham's answer, u can set the state like this also:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        Day:false,
        Open:false,
        Close:true
    }
      this.pushTime = this.pushTime.bind(this);
  }

  logState(){
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  pushTime(event){
    let state = this.state;
    console.log('Clicked ', event.target.id, event.target.value);
    state[event.target.id]=!state[event.target.id];
    this.setState({state});
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <input type='checkbox' id='Day' name='Day' onClick={this.pushTime} checked={this.state.Day}/>
         <input type='checkbox' id='Open' name='Open' onClick={this.pushTime} checked={this.state.Open}/>
         <input type='checkbox' id='Close' name='Close' onClick={this.pushTime} checked={this.state.Close}/>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

check the `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/vhavwcbh/

Answer (score 0):

```
  pushTime(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var stateObject=function(){
      let returnObj={}
      returnObj[this.target.id]=this.target.value
      return returnObj
    }.bind(event)();

    this.setState(stateObject)
  }
```